# find most popular tag

Tags: php, mysql, smf, smf-forum

Is there a way to find the most popular tag in forum posts? For example, I have a tag called `[card=x]cardname[/card]`. I want to find all `[card]` tags sorted by the number of times `x` occurs. Also note that there can be multiple `[card]` tags in a single post.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you a lot:

http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/comment/7200

Assuming that you know how you total the query from there. If not, it will be something like:

```
SET @findme="[card";
SELECT
  count((LENGTH(n.FIELD) - LENGTH(REPLACE(n.FIELD, @findme, ""))) / LENGTH(@findme)) AS findme_count
FROM table n
ORDER BY findme_count DESC;
```

You would have to loop or case that for each tag. I'm guessing REGEXP is overrated for this, since you probably only need to look for something like "[card" as opposed to "\\\[card .*?\\\].*?\\\[\\\/card\\\]"

EDIT: I'm sorry, I misread the post, it looks like you don't want to count tags but rather parameters, in which case you would need a capturing REGEXP.

Comment: i've seen that. while that would work for finding how many tags there are, I want to know how many of a specific card. More precisely, i wan the tags ordered by how many times the `x` in the tag occurs.

Comment: Aye, I'm sorry I misread that. The above is still the right concept, just without the capturing REGEXP. :(